# iOS14 missing buttons in "Save to Files" menu

Tags: ios, swift, action, ios14, uidocumentinteractioncontroller

I spot that my code behaves differently on iOS13 / iOS14. I am downloading pdf file and showing it with UIDocumentInteractionController

```
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let controladorDoc = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: PdfUrl)
        controladorDoc.delegate = self
        controladorDoc.presentPreview(animated: true)
    }
```

after pdf is shown I am clicking "Save" button. Here is the difference:

[image: iOS13]

[image: iOS14]

Save and Cancel buttons are missing. How to fix that ? I was thinking about overloading buttons in actions menu but I didn't find how to make that.

Comment: Are they missing or are they just white? Try tapping where the button should be and see if that works. Are you using UIAppearance?

Comment: Hi @EmilioPelaez yes, that's something which I forgot to add, they seems to be white. When I click in corner it's working. I am not using UIAppearance. Only UIDocumentInteractionController + delegate documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController

Comment: UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I was wrong I am using UIAppearance on the very beginning in AppDelegate, faulty line of code:
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
Please post your comment as answer I will mark it as solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your buttons are working but are invisible it's very likely that you are using `UIAppearance` somewhere and that's causing your buttons to become the same color as the navigation bar.